# Why can't change source code provider in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I just signed up for Team Foundation Services Cloud Service since I've failed to implement TFS on my server and local machine. I want to change the source provider from the previous TFS system I abandoned to the new cloud one. It still refers to the old one.  I've gone through all the options available, including running a program off of CodePlex that will remove source control bindings. For some reason, it refuses to allow me to unmap my source control from the old server and bind it to the new TFS cloud service.  Why?

EDIT: I noticed there are some invisible .SUO files in my project directories.  Is this where TFS 2012 stores it's settings? I deleted these files and somehow I was able to map my source to the new server. There were work spaces that appeared when I ran TFS from the command line that didn't appear in the in VS.

Comment: any chance of some screenshots or further explanation?

Comment: What is the source control provider you want to use?

Comment: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Your%20TFS%20Source%20Control%20Bindings

Comment: Ed, this assumes you can communicate with the old server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything including uninstalling TFS server locally and removing all traces of the old server connection info on my system and I still couldn't get it to switch to another server. It was like a pit bull that wouldn't let go. I had the taught that Microsoft wanted to make their TFS look less cluttered by hiding its ugly plumbing in invisible folders like Git and Mercurial. Sure enough, there were SUO files hidden in my directory and subfolders. I recursively deleted all them and was able to connect to the new server.

The following command should recursively remove all hidden SUO files from your solution folder:

del /S /A:H  *.suo